# Python Regex for Words & single space

Tags: python, regex, string

I am using re.sub in order to forcibly convert a "bad" string into a "valid" string via regex. I am struggling with creating the right regex that will parse a string and "remove the bad parts". Specifically, I would like to force a string to be all alphabetical, and allow for a single space between words. Any values that disagree with this rule I would like to substitute with ''. This includes multiple spaces. Any help would be appreciated!

```
import re
list_of_strings = ["3He2l2lo Wo45rld!", "Hello World- -number two-", "Hello    World    number .. three"
for str in list_of_strings:
    print re.sub(r'[^A-Za-z]+([^\s][A-Za-z])*', '' , str)
```

I would like the output to be:

Hello World

Hello World number two

Hello World number three

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try if the following works. It matches both groups of characters to remove, but only when there is at least an space in them subsitutes it with an space.

```
import re
list_of_strings = ["3He2l2lo Wo45rld!", "Hello World- -number two-", "Hello    World    number .. three"]
for str in list_of_strings:
    print(re.sub(r'((?:[^A-Za-z\s]|\s)+)', lambda x: ' ' if ' ' in x.group(0) else '' , str))
```

It yields:

```
Hello World
Hello World number two
Hello World number three
```

Answer (score 3):

I would prefer to have 2 passes to simplify the regex. First pass removes non-alphas, second removes multiple spaces.

```
pass1 = re.sub(r'[^A-Za-z\s]','',str)    # remove non-alpha
pass2 = re.sub(r'\s+',' ',pass1);       # collapses spaces to 1
```