# Check if DataFrame column contains only strings

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have a DataFrame `df`:

```
     A     B
0    a     1
1    a1    3
2    b_    5
3    c(    7
```

I would like to get only these elements (e.x as a list) from the the column `A` that are strings, so in this case only `a` would be returned. I thought of `.str.contains()` but I'd rather use something that bases on types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use regex with `^` for start of string, then letters `a-z` and `A-Z` and last `$` for end of string in [`Series.str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html):

```
df = df[df['A'].str.contains('^[a-zA-Z]$')]
print (df)
   A  B
0  a  1
```

If want `A` filtered column to list:

```
L = df.loc[df['A'].str.contains('^[a-zA-Z]$'), 'A'].tolist()
print (L)
['a']
```

EDIT:

```
print (df)
      A  B
0   a d  1
1  a gh  3
2    b_  5
3    c(  7

#https://stackoverflow.com/a/18752121/2901002
df = df[~df['A'].str.contains('[^A-Za-z\s]')]
print (df)
      A  B
0   a d  1
1  a gh  3
```

Comment: @thesecond - exclude? Not include?

Comment: Right! Sorry, my bad.

Comment: @thesecond - also if space only should be filtered? Or only space with letters? Answer was edited.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `str.contains` with a negative expression:

```
# ^ inside [ ] indicates negative selection
df[~df['A'].str.contains('[^a-zA-Z]')]
```

Or you can `match` the whole string with alpha-characters:

```
# ^ indicates start of the string, $ indicates the end
df[df['A'].str.match('^[a-zA-Z]$')]
```

Output:

```
   A  B
0  a  1
```

Answer (score 2):

We have `isalpha`

```
m=df.A.str.isalpha()
Out[192]: 
0     True
1    False
2    False
3    False
Name: A, dtype: bool
df[m]
```

Comment: @thesecond what you mean exclude ? the one contain white space should be removed as well ?

Comment: I would like to get only strings, but also allow presence of spaces ' '. If I had 'Great Britain', 'Germany', 'France1', I would like my output to be True, True, False.