# How remove records which are not alphabets inside specific column in pandas data frame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have data frame`(df)` as shown below and I want to drop records which contain special characters and numbers.

**INPUT**

```
df

 A     B
 ASR    IN
 33AB   ST
 AS_TY  YT
 45 TYY IN 
 TY HG  SG
 TRD    US
 YTR    WS
```

**EXPECTED OUTPUT**

```
 A     B
 ASR    IN
 TRD    US
 YTR    WS
```

How this be achieved in pandas dataframe

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if DataFrame column contains only strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61613582/check-if-dataframe-column-contains-only-strings)

Answer (score 3):

This is a good job for a regex.

If you want to use only A:

```
out = df[df['A'].str.match('(?i)[a-z]+$')]
```

For all columns:

```
out = df[df.apply(lambda c: c.str.match('(?i)[a-z]+$')).all(1)]
```

output:

```
     A   B
0  ASR  IN
5  TRD  US
6  YTR  WS
```

Answer (score 2):

Check `isalpha`

```
df[df.A.astype(str).str.isalpha()]
```

Comment: Just curious, how `isalpha` handle non-English unicode?

Comment: @BENY getting an error  -Cannot mask with non-boolean array containing NA / NaN values

Comment: @QuangHoang python2 should not work , let check my current set up

Comment: @QuangHoang it work for French and Spanish

Comment: @aeapen adding astype str

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex match to find same,
example

df[df.A.str.contains('/^[A-Za-z]+$/', regex= True, na=False)]

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way to do this is by using a helper column to mask the rows that contain non alpha numerical characters as follows :

```py
import pandas as pd

# dummy example
df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : ['ABC', 'acfx', 'a34xxf_', 'a_9R', 'rty']})

# create helper column
df['mask']  = df['A'].apply(lambda x : x.isalnum())

# get the rows that contain only alpha numerical characters
df[df['mask']==True].drop(['mask'], axis = 1)

>>>
    A
0   ABC
1   acfx
4   rty
```